# How to use same Test fragment with different user credentials in same Test Script in JMeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, fragment

I have created a Test plan in JMeter consisting 5 different modules (Transaction Controllers) and need to execute the same. But, there is a one Test Fragment for login module which is common for all the modules where username is passing though CSV and Passwords is created using Function in JMeter.
Login steps are common for all the 5 modules but to execute the Test Plan, I need different user credentials for all the 5 modules.

How to achieve the same in JMeter like same Test fragment but multiple user credentials in same test plan?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, the way the CSV Data Set Config works depends on 2 factors:

1. [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
2. [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy)

So given all the Test Fragments are in the CSV Data Set Config's scope - by default each user will read next line on each iteration. The behaviour can be amended by the aforementioned "Sharing Mode" setting